# Reading Files in Parallel mpi4py

Tags: python-3.x, mpi4py

I have a series of n files that I'd like to read in parallel using mpi4py. Every file contains a column vector and, as final result, I want to obtain a matrix containing all the single vectors as X = [x1 x2 ... xn].

In the first part of the code I create the list containing all the names of the files and I distribute part of the list to the different cores through the scatter method.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from mpi4py import MPI

comm   = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank   = comm.Get_rank()
nprocs = comm.Get_size()

folder     = "data/"    # Input directory
files      = []         # File List

# Create File List -----------------------------------------------------------
if rank == 0:

    for i in range(1,2000):
        filename = "file_" + str(i) + ".csv"
        files = np.append(files,filename)

    print("filelist complete!")

    # Determine the size of each sub task
    ave, res = divmod(files.size, nprocs)
    counts   = [ave + 1 if p < res else ave for p in range(nprocs)]

    # Determine starting and ending indices of each sub-task
    starts = [sum(counts[:p]) for p in range(nprocs)]
    ends   = [sum(counts[:p+1]) for p in range(nprocs)] 

    # Convert data into list of arrays
    fileList = [files[starts[p]:ends[p]] for p in range(nprocs)]

else:

    fileList = None 

fileList = comm.scatter(fileList, root = 0)
```

Here I create a matrix X where to store the vectors.

```
# Variables Initialization ---------------------------------------------------

# Creation Support Vector
vector = pd.read_csv(folder + fileList[0])
vector = vector.values

vectorLength = len(vector)

# Matrix
X = np.ones((vectorLength, len(fileList)))
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here, I read the different files and I append the column vector to the matrix X. With the gather method I store all the X matrix calculated by the single cores into one single matrix X. The X matrix resulting from the gather method is a list of 2D numpy arrays. As final step, I reorganize the list X into a matrix

```
# Reading Files -----------------------------------------------------------
for i in range(len(fileList)):

    data     = pd.read_csv(folder + fileList[i])
    data     = np.array(data.values)
        
    X[:,i] = data[:,0]


X = comm.gather(X, root = 0)


if rank == 0:

    X_tot = np.empty((vectorLength, 1))
    

    for i in range(nprocs):

        X_proc  = np.array(X[i])
        X_tot   = np.append(X_tot, X_proc, axis=1)

    X_tot = X_tot[:,1:]
    X     = X_tot
    del X_tot
    print("printing X", X)
```

The code works fine. I tested it on a small dataset and did what it is meant to do. However I tried to run it on a large dataset and I got the following error:

```
X = comm.gather(X[:,1:], root = 0)
  File "mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1578, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.gather
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 773, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_gather
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 778, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_gather
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 191, in mpi4py.MPI.pickle_allocv
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 182, in mpi4py.MPI.pickle_alloc
SystemError: Negative size passed to PyBytes_FromStringAndSize
```

It seems a really general error, however I could process the same data in serial mode without problems or in parallel without using all the n files. I also noticed that only the rank 0 core seems to work, while the others seem to do nothing.

This is my first project using mpi4py so I'm sorry if the code is not perfect and if I have committed any conceptual mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This error typically occurs when the data passed between MPI processes exceeds a certain size (I think 2GB). It's supposed to be fixed with future MPI versions, but for now, you'll probably have to resort to a workaround like storing your data on the hard disk and reading it with each process separately...
See for example here: https://github.com/mpi4py/mpi4py/issues/23

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).